# Ajax long poll post data to php

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code that runs every few second to grab data from the php file:

```
<script>            
$(document).ready(function(){
    function doPoll(){
        var cid= <?php echo $user2 ?>;
        $.post('chatfunction.php') .done(function(data) { /* process */ 
            document.getElementById("#chatarea").innerHTML = data;
        }) .always(function() { 
            setTimeout(doPoll, 5000); 
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

This is not the usual ajax format, however, i need to POST a variable across to the php file as well, may i know how i can integrate that in this piece of code?

Thanks!

Comment: Use [**.post**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: ah ha thanks! jQuery post seems to be little different from the ajax version.

Comment: no point creating a post if you don't send any data

Comment: @charlietfl True; that's just a link, though, not a suggestion to send an empty request.

Comment: @EdCottrell I meant in OP code

Comment: yeah i do understand, thats why i was trying to find out how to add the data inside

Comment: `$.post('chatfunction.php', {cid: cid}).done..`

Answer (score 0):

> not sure how to set the timeout and to make it such that it runs continuously regardless of whether there is an error or not

For this you need [`setinterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp):

```
$document.ready(function() {
  setinterval( function(){ doPoll() }, 3000 );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

and you should put the `function doPoll()` outside the `document.ready`

It should like this:

```
$document.ready(function() {
    setInterval(doPoll(), 5000); // It will run doPoll() function every 5 seconds
});


function doPoll(){
     // and the rest of the code
}
```

This is the proper way of calling a function or to trigger your post request on `doPoll()` function.

AND YOU CAN ALSO DO A POST REQUEST USING AJAX

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "YOU_URL_HERE", // your URL
  data: {param1:"params1", params2:"params2", params3:"params3"}, // parameters you need to pass
  success: function(){
     alert("SUCCESS"); // If success
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("ERROR"); // If error
}
});
```

**EDIT:**
Added setInterval so that `doPoll()` function will execute every 5 seconds

Comment: you say it should be done outside `document.ready` but give no reason why

Comment: hi @Newbie, i did look at ajax post, but not sure how to set the timeout and to make it such that it runs continuously regardless of whether there is an error or not

Comment: Hi @wishfulthinking I just edited my answer.. Just check it out... Hope it'll helps you